# thingsboard: reformat shared attribute JSON before publishing via MQTT

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I need to send configuration data to a device from Thingsboard (CE) via MQTT. The device expects a specific JSON structure and changing the firmware of the device is not an option.

I looked into the [client side RPC API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#client-side-rpc) but the required pub/sub scheme is not supported by the device.

I looked into the [Attributes API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#subscribe-to-attribute-updates-from-the-server) which seemed promising.

I tried to use the [JSON value support](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#json-value-support) for shared attributes but it stores and subsequntly publishes the attribute as a key/value pair with my JSON as the value:

```
{
"sharedAttributeKey": {
    "myKey1": "myValue1,
    "myKey2": "myValue2"
    }
}
```

But I need it so publish:

```
{
  "myKey1": "myValue1,
  "myKey2": "myValue2"
}
```

I tried to use the rule chain to reformat the JSON to the required format, but Thingsboard publishes the message before the rule chain is executed. What am I doing wrong?
Any helo  would be highly aprreciated.